# OutOfMemoryError and EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException in Geonetwork 3.12.1.0

Tags: java, geonetwork

I'm experiencing some troubles with Geonetwork 3.12.1.0 and didn't find any solution, so please forgive me if this was asked before.

We have a Geonetwork 3.12.1.0 running on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS with 4GB of RAM. This GN instance has only 7 metadata records that are added by hand, so we are using the default H2 database.

When we tried to edit any record, we got the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error, so I added the line `export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms256m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"` to the setenv.sh file and restarted the Tomcat service. This caused that we now obtain the `EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException` error when we try to edit any existing metadata and the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error when we try to create a new one.

What should I do next to try to solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem when updating to GN v3.12.2: `EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException` when trying to create a new dataset. The weird thing is, I have a staging environment that works and a live environment that does not.